# In mysql triggers is there a way to know which column is getting update?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Does mysql have a statement that helps me to know which column is being modified in a trigger?

I already tried this way:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
        IF OLD.ID != NEW.ID THEN
            INSERT INTO backupTable
                (ID,back_ID) values (NEW.ID,OLD.ID);
        END IF
//
DELIMITER;
```

But my teacher said that is another way more effective than compare `OLD.ID` with `NEW.ID`

Comment: It's unusual to update the ID of a row, that's usually the primary key that stays the same while you update other columns.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in way to tell which column is being modified. You'd have to compare `OLD.colname` to `NEW.colname` for each column.

Comment: What do you want to do with the name of the column being updated? What if it's updating multiple columns?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your teacher to explain the method they had in mind?

Comment: i totally agree here with @Barmar ... Also arn't you making some kind of home made (row/record based) version off [Binary Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html)  now ?

Answer (score 0):

From inside a row level trigger in MySQL, it's not possible to directly determine which columns are referenced in the statement. MySQL doesn't give us access to the statement that cause the trigger to be fired.

Within an `UPDATE` trigger, we can access the "NEW" and "OLD" values of columns, and we can do comparison.

Given a statement such as this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET fo = IFNULL(fo,0) + 1 WHERE id = 42 ;
```

The `id` value wouldn't be changed, but if a matching row (or rows) exist, the value of the `fo` column in those rows will certainly be changed.

To detect that in a trigger, we need to compare `OLD.fo` to `NEW.fo`. We should also take into account a change from NULL to non-NULL or vice versa.

To detect changes to any number of columns, we would need to check each column.

```
  IF  ( OLD.id   <=> NEW.id   )
  AND ( OLD.fee  <=> NEW.fee  )
  AND ( OLD.fi   <=> NEW.fi   )
  AND ( OLD.fo   <=> NEW.fo   )
  AND ( OLD.fum  <=> NEW.fum  ) THEN
     -- the values of these columns (id, fee, fi, fo, fum) is not changed
  ELSE
     -- the value of at least one of the columns id, fee, fi, fo, or fum is changed
  END IF
```

---

The null-safe comparison `<=>` (spaceship) operator is MySQL shorthand

```
a <=> b
```

is equivalent to:

```
( ( a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL AND a = b ) OR ( a IS NULL AND b IS NULL ) )
```

---

The normative pattern is for `id` column to be a surrogate primary key, with most or all of the desirable properties: non-null-able, simple datatype, unique, anonymous, immutable, ...

It would be very odd use-case to have the surrogate `id` primary key value of a row changed.

---

Comment: @RaymondNijland:  yes, you are right.   the null-safe comparison will return 0 or 1, and won't return a NULL.   to get truly equivalent behavior, we could do  `( ( a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL AND a = b ) OR ( a IS NULL AND b IS NULL ) )` , or wrap an expression in a CASE or IF() function

Comment: `a <=> b` is meant to "support" and be [equivalent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) to the ANSI/ISO SQL `<column> IS NOT DISTINCT FROM <column>`  syntax..  Yes i agree the equivalent writting can be multiple ways.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: thank you for the insight.  I mostly use the spaceship operator to do "equality" comparisons, when I want NULL values to be considered "unequal" to a non-NULL value, and "equal" to another NULL value. Such a convenient shorthand, without mucking with explicit IS NULL tests, and the ANDing and the ORing and the parens to specify the order of operations